# Deploying zend skeleton application on openshift server

Tags: php, zend-framework, openshift, paas

I successfully deployed the skeleton application on openshift paas server.
Using Git I put my code in the folder /php.

And now, I can reach the application at the url:
=> http://zend-application.rhcloud.com/public/

In local I created the vitrual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zend.localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/zend/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:/wamp/www/zend/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to create a similar vhost on openshift server and access the appli with the base URL:
=> http://zend-application.rhcloud.com/   (without */public/)

Many thanks!
Ced.

Comment: Can you help me understand the steps you use to create your app?  I wasn't able to reproduce this by creating the zend app with 'rhc app create zendtest zend-5.6'.  My sample application shows up here: http://zendtest-macdomain.rhcloud.com

Comment: There are also other ways to deploy your application using zendserver and zend studio:  https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-zend-and-openshift

Comment: Hello, I didn't use RHC command yet.

Comment: I follow the getting-started guide you talked about. But my first problem is that I need to provide an url such : http://{appName}-{namespace}.rhcloud.com/{project-name}

Comment: This is working fine even if I don't use zend studio but Eclipse PDT. So my question could be, how to remove the "/{project-name}" to access the API in the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy content of public into php directory itself. and make sure your .htaccess file is like code given below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And modify Application path in index.php file like below:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));
```

Then this will work properly. This worked for me in [My site](http://php1-ss1.rhcloud.com).

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink for your zf public folder and name it php:

From your project directory 
first remove php folder (if it exists)
then 
`ln -s public/ php`
then simply push your code via the rhc tool

That should make you project visible @  http://zend-application.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Good idea... I'll try when I got some time! Thanks.